# Target child element of hovered element (animejs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

I have these elements:

```
<a class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</a>
```

I want to target child element only when parent is hover. So, I tryed with jQuery:

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){

  let child = $(this).children('.child'); // select child of $(this)

  anime({
    targets: child,
    translateX: 250,
  });

});
```

This doesn't work. My guess is that [animejs can't target jQuery elements](https://animejs.com/documentation/#cssSelector).

So, is it possible to achieve it with vanilla JS? I mean, can I select a child element of hovered element with vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Using JS node lists

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.parent'); // create a nodelist of elements

elements.forEach(listeners); // iterate the node list

// Finally, add listeners to each node of nodelist
function listeners(currentIndex) {
  currentIndex.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    let child = currentIndex.getElementsByClassName('child')

    anime({
      targets: child,
      translateX: 250,
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use JQuery to activate the hover listener but the key is to find the [correct target for anime.js](https://animejs.com/documentation/#domNode) to utilize. Try this:

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){
  anime({
    targets: this.querySelector('.child'),
    translateX: 250,
  });
});
```

the **this** selector refers to the parent that is being hovered. The code will translate any elements that have class "child".

Hope that helps -- ran across this question while looking for the answer myself!